# Finding the dimension of $\mathbb{F}[x]/p(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, let $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ and let $\text{deg}(p) \geq 1$. I'm looking at a proof which shows that $\mathbb{F}[x]/p(x)$ is an integral domain implies that $\mathbb{F}[x]/p(x)$ is a field. The proof states that $\text{dim}_\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{F}[x]/p(x))$ is finite and uses another theorem to prove the claim.

My question is: What is $\text{dim}_\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{F}[x]/p(x))$ exactly?

Comment: Dimension as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry I know that, but I mean how do you calculate it? I have another question which asks me to calculate that dimension.

Comment: Say $p(x)$ has degree $n$. Can you come up with a nice set of coset representatives for the quotient ring?

Comment: @blueto32: The dimension is $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dim_{\mathbf F}\mathbf F[x]/(p(x))=\deg p$.

Indeed, let $d=\deg p$; the  cosets of $1,x,\dots, x^{d-1} $ are generators of $\,\mathbf F[x]/(p(x))$, and they are linearly independent because any linear relation between these elements would translate into a polynomial of degree $<d$ divisible by $p$, which is impossible since the coefficients belong to a field.

If $A=\mathbf F[x]/(p(x))$ is an integral domain, multiplication par any element $a\neq 0$ is an $\mathbf F$-endomorphism $m_a$ of $A$ which is *injective*. Now for endomorphisms of finite-dimensional vector spaces, injective $\iff$ surjective. This implies that$1$ is attained by $m_a$, i.e.  there exists $x\in A$ such that $ax=1$. In other words, any $a$ is invertible.

Comment: Could you explain how you got the dimensin to be the degree of $p$?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.